# vscode ftp как загружать скомпилированные файлы?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Второй день ищу ответ. Как в vscode по ftp загружать скомпилированные файлы sass или js. Пользуюсь gulp но хотелось бы узнать без него можно это как то сделать?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp - смотрели ?

Comment: да смотрел. но я так и не нашел настроек для мониторинга. А так это работает только с сохраненными файлами а не с измененными

Answer (score 0):

может пригодится кому

```
"uploadOnSave": false,
"watcher": {
    "files": "**",
    "autoUpload": true,
    "autoDelete": true
}
```

[плагин](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp)